# How to extend the information that provides Intellisense using the Visual Studio SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

In C# or Vb.Net, using the Visual Studio 2013 SDK, how I could add an additional element on Intellisense when the info of a member is shown?.

My intention is not to add a completion/suggestion element, I would like to add custom additional info below the info that is shown for a member that can throw an exception like a method, function or property (getter/setter), not a keyword.

I read a little bit the members of **[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.aspx)** namespace but I didn't take any clear idea about it.

My goal, with the help I could get here, is to find the answer to develop a simple extension that will add (documented)Exception information for members, something like this:

[image]

I wonder to bring back this useful feature in Visual Studio for C#, and add it also for VB.Net, then if successful I'll share it for free with all yours like I did in the past with this useful extension:

- **[Snippet Tool - Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/776ff18b-d8a8-43cc-82c1-a65a8509202b)**

Just I comment that because any help could be rewarded for all of us in that way!.

---

Additionally to my question, and only Additionally, if someone could start guiding me about how to figure out the way to retrieve the Xml documentation of the members ( `<exception cref="Exception name">` ) to do this, or maybe a simple way, I would be very grateful.

**EDIT**:

About the Xml documentation, I get the idea to use the Visual Studio **object browser** to inspect the exceptions of the member that will be listed by Intellisense instead of messing with Reflection? to get exception info. That could be a better and viable way to do it once I can figure out how to automate the object browser from SDK, but I'm just commenting this, maybe that will be a new question once this question could be solved, because firstly I need to solve this step, I hope so.

Comment: How is this question different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460002)?

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå Thanks for comment. In that question I asked for the existence of a guided way to enable the feature from the IDE (such a hidden option or command), or from an existing 3rd party extension. This question is different, this is programming-language specific to start trying to develop an extension from scratch to add that feature.

Comment: Personally, I would not want complete, verbose documentation in Intellisense.  The arguments and return are appropriate for when you are typing a method name.  Looking things up in Object Browser to see commentary and/or exceptions is very much a different step (for me).

Comment: As stated in your previous question even in VS2105 C# does not even have this capability anymore so I would guess as mentioned before that it's not likely you can implement this functionality.

Comment: @Karen Payne and Plutonix Thanks for comment. Please be aware that a lot of Visual Studio professional extensions (non-open source) like for example Telerik (Just Code) interacts with IntelliSense to add extra information, then, with this argument I can confirm its possible to extend Intellisense, more than that, there is the IntelliSense class that I linked in my question to play with things!, but I can't figure how to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are few types of `IntelliSence` extensibility points that you need to use for each of the following cases:

- The tool-tip shown **when hovering text element** is called ***`QuickInfo`*** tool-tip, and can be implemented by yourself via inheriting from [`IQuickInfoSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iquickinfosource(v=vs.120).aspx) interface and creating a matching [`IIntellisenseController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iintellisensecontroller(v=vs.120).aspx). A full walk-through can be found [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee197646(v=vs.120).aspx):

  - Example:

    [image: QuickInfo Tool-Tip]
  - Make sure to make your [`IQuickInfoSourceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iquickinfosourceprovider(v=vs.120).aspx) load your `IQuickInfoSource` ***before*** the default `Visual-Studio` one by using the [`Order` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.utilities.orderattribute(v=vs.120).aspx) - otherwise the default `QuickInfo` is not going to be shown:

    ```
    [Order(Before = "Default Quick Info Presenter")]
    ```
- The tool-tip shown when writing method name which shows it's signature is called ***`Signature Help`*** and can be implemented by inheriting [`ISignatureHelpSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.isignaturehelpsource(v=vs.120).aspx) in a very similar way to the `QuickInfo` tool-tip. A full walkthrough can be found [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee334194(v=vs.120).aspx):

  - Example:

    [image: Signature Help]
- ***`Code Snippets`*** - which are irrelevant for you.
- ***`Statement Completions`*** - which are irrelevant for you.

Note that you will need to make an `IClassifier` in your project for the tool-tips to be displayed, with this you can also modify the view so that the `Exceptions` will be viewed differently as you wish. [Guide on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885492(v=vs.120).aspx).

Getting the information on the methods on the other hand is up to you. you can use an external manual source and use it in your `IQuickInfoSource` or read it from a matching `XML Comment` document by analysing the `ITextStructureNavigator`'s read word using [`Roslyn`](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) over the code document that you are navigating.

Sorry if it was a little abstract answer but this is a very broad question and there are many ways to implement such an extension.

***P.S.: I've managed to make a similar extension in low quality in order to study this field so if you have any following questions about the implementation itself feel free to ask.***