# XML Comments - Exceptions not showing in intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, xml-comments

I have a method that throws an exception under the namespace: MyApp.Domain. I have some of my custom exceptions under the namespace: MyApp.Domain.Exceptions. So what I have is this:

```
using MyApp.Domain.Exceptions
using System;

namespace MyApp.Domain
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        ///<summary>This method does some stuff</summary>
        ///<exception cref="MyCustomExeption">MyCustomException if x</exception>
        ///<exception cref="Exception">GenericException if y</exception>
        public void DoStuff(){

            //Does stuff

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting my summary with intellisense but not exceptions. Do I have to use an include and create an external xml comment file since they are under different namespaces? Neither of the exceptions are showing up in intellisense, mycustomexception or system.exception.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you. Do you mean that when you start type "new myc", intellisense is not showing your custom exception?

Comment: I am not getting a list of exceptions in intellisense when I am typing DoStuff() but I am getting the summary.

Comment: Not showing exceptions even after completion of typing the full method name.

Comment: This feature is no longer supported in VS2015 and is a duplicate to these answers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460002/show-exceptions-in-intellisense/

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792546/vs-2015-intellisense-exceptions-thrown-not-previewed

Comment: @GibralterTop - that issue was resolved in Update 1 and works as expected (or at least as it used to...)

Comment: @jdl134679 Correct. I am now seeing the exceptions. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually the `Exception` tag will be visible once you type the full method name then on mouse over.

and if you wanted to show exception as soon as u started typing the method name you have to provide the exception in summary tag separated by `<para>`

```
     /// <summary>
    /// this is my method for date convert        
    /// <para>Exception:</para>
    /// Exception - this will appear as soon as you started typing the method name and method over.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
```

hope it make clear what u wanted.

to show the anything whatever u want as soon as user start typing the name of the method. you have to provide inside the summary tag only.

Comment: On completing the typing and after endline character I still don't see it. Mouse over still does not show the Exception list upon completion.

Comment: for predefine .net method its showing ??  ur xml comments seems correct to me. did u try restarting VS? as some time intellisense goes out ofmind.

Comment: Well... it was showing but is not now for predefined as well. Restarted VS and rebooted PC but to no avail. VS2015. I assume intellisense has "stepped out to lunch". Unfortunate, since I am just starting with XML Comments. Will user your <para></para> answer for the time being. Thank you!

Comment: Feature not supported in VS2015.

Comment: Feature fixed in VS2015 Update 1