# How can I display the description of tag <Exception> in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

```
public class TestClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Do my work
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">This is a Description</exception>
    public static void DoWork()
    {
        //do my work
    }
}
```

```
TestClass.DoWork();
```

How do I display text "This is a description" in "Quick Info" when I hover over a method?

[image: Test class picture]

[image: Test class call picture]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML Comments - Exceptions not showing in intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813808/xml-comments-exceptions-not-showing-in-intellisense) and [In C# XML Documentation, only the summary tag is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833812/in-c-sharp-xml-documentation-only-the-summary-tag-is-working)

Answer (score 1):

This feature isn't implemented yet.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1515

For now you can duplicate this info into summary tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following comment to get what you wanted.

```
public class TestClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Do my work
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="This is description"></exception> 
    public static void DoWork()
    {
        // do my work
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice hack but this time you don't show the type of the exception that is thrown.